# Question on work done and frame of reference

Tags: forces, kinematics, reference-frames, work, inertial-frames

While solving a question  which is.....
If an object is kept in a non inertial frame moving up with acceleration 'A' find the work done by pseudo force on the object taking a person standing on ground as frame of reference.

Now what confuses me is that I have read that pseudo force is used when we are taking the accelerating lift itself as reference frame... But in respect to ground it should have no significance. Then isn't this question contradictory?

Comment: The question is pretty confusing. Can you make sure to give us the **exact** wording? Because this way it does seem contradictory or incomplete.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. There is no pseudo force when taking ground/earth as a frame of reference. Therefore, only work is done by the normal force and against the force of gravity. I wonder if it is a trick question, or if the question meant the person on the "ground" is on the ground of the non-inertial frame.